# Objects.index(object) while using ajax pagination?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination

Using Ajax pagination via the will_paginate gem I'm having an issue rendering my collection since adding the pagination: I cannot display the indexes properly.

For example, in my view, I render the collection:

```
<%= render @songs %>
```

In the song partial, I have the following to help make the list look pretty:

```
<%= @songs.index(song) + 1 %>
```

My pagination is twitter-style, in that every time someone clicks "more", it shoots out 5 more songs. The issue is the index of the collection is always 0-4 as my collection is limited to 5 via the pagination arguments.

What should I do to get these indexes working? Should I be getting two collections in my controller, one for pagination and one that is not simply for rendering the index?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
(params[:page].to_i * @songs_per_page) + @songs.index(song) + 1
```

(adjust as needed for fencepost errors)

Comment: Thanks for the help Taryn. If anyone else comes across this, I had to convert params[:page] to an integer for rendering in the view.